# UIViewController Container view content extends container bounds

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uicontainerview

I am trying to use a UIViewController container to load a reusable storyboard view. I am using AutoLayout and targeting iOS 8. The problem I am facing is that the loaded container container is not adjusting to the container view but rather it's parent view.

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

And here is what the result is in the simulator. I added a pink background to the container to show it's bounds. As you can see the right button weirdly extending both the bounds of the container and also the screen. After rotating the view it will oddly become correct.

[image: In simulator]

Even after rotation the content of the loaded container view is not adjusting itself to it's parent (or even parent's parent). It is adjusting to the topmost view. See the example below where I've decreased the width of the container view (see pink background) but the loaded view is extending it.

[image]

Update 1: The constraint for the views in my Container view are setup like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you men you're using "auto-constraint"? You mean AutoLayout, or that you didn't set any constraints and let it size by itself?

Comment: What are the constraints applied to the containerView? You can embed the containerView in another view and set this view to Clip Subviews. This should restrain it to the desired area.

Comment: Yes AutoLayout is used. I tried to place the Container in a normal View. If I use "Clip Subviews" on the Container view it will cut out everything on "on top" of the pink area.

Comment: Ok. Show us the constraints applied to the container view please.

Comment: first of all just use "constrain to margins" button from the "pin" menu from bottom to all constraints

Comment: Not sure if that's what you meant @Bhavin but deselecting "Relative to margin" on all horizontal constraints made it work as intended! Thanks

Comment: ya thats what i trying to tell you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by selecting `Relative to margin` on all horizontal constraints. Could also have selected `constrain to margins` when creating the constraints.